# PHP | How do I access/modify a switch statement variable globally?

Tags: php, html, switch-statement, global-variables, undefined

Perhaps this question is worded wrong, but I am having some trouble with my PHP switch statement below.
My goal is to have access to the $page variable across all files. I have tried to do this with sessions, but could not get it to work. An example of my code is shown below. Could this problem be solved with **$_GLOBALS** or **$_SESSIONS**? Please point me in the right direction.

***Index.php***

```
<?php
    
    /* Fetch needed files. */
    require_once 'app/paths.php';
    require_once THEME_LAYOUT_PATH . 'container.phtml';
    
    if(!isset($_GET['page']) || $_GET['page'] == ''){
        $page = 'home'; 
        } else {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }
    
    $layoutPath = 'themes/neutron/layout/' . $page . '/' . $page . '.phtml';
    
    switch($page) 
    {
        case 'home':
            include $layoutPath;
            break;
        case 'login':
            include $layoutPath;
            break;
        case 'register':
            include $layoutPath;
            break;
        default:
            include 'themes/neutron/layout/404/404.phtml';
    
    }
    
    ?>
```

***Container.phtml***

```
<html>
<?php if($page == 'login'){ ?> //Error: $page is undefined 
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "<?php ASSETS_PATH . 'css/file.css' ?>">
<?php } ?>


</html>
```

Comment: `require_once THEME_LAYOUT_PATH . 'container.phtml';` is before `$page = ` Can also simplify that assignment to `$page = !empty($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'home';`

Comment: It also looks like you are missing an `echo` here `<?php ASSETS_PATH . 'css/file.css' ?>`

Comment: I don't understand the need for your switch statement at all

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Good point, since all cases do the same thing except the default.

Comment: It should just be something like `if (in_array($page, ["home", "login", "register"]))`

Comment: @IncredibleHat The `switch` statement is essentially the whitelist for using the user input.

Comment: @Barmar Give me an example of using an array in my codes case. I am trying to keep things organized.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I am new to PHP, I dont see how that can be a security issue when their is not input field for that .

Comment: @Neutron Barmar already gave you an example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178494/php-how-do-i-access-modify-a-switch-statement-variable-globally#comment111720663_63178494. That replaces the `switch` do `include inside that.. and for the else do your default value.

Comment: @Neutron General rule of thumb: Anything in `$_GET` or `$_POST` and even `$_REQUEST` can come from the outside world. Never trust values in those superglobals. Always sanitize/whitelist from them. Keeping your switch in, helps, because you are effectively whitelisting the value and only including a file if the case matches. Just be careful with it.

Answer (score 2):

You're requiring container.phtml before you set the $page variable. The files included in your switch statement should all have access to the global $page variable, assuming they aren't wrapped inside a class, function, or other construct.

Edit: Here's what your code would look like with this change:

```
<?php
    
    if(!isset($_GET['page']) || $_GET['page'] == ''){
        $page = 'home'; 
        } else {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }
    
    /* Fetch needed files. */
    require_once 'app/paths.php';
    require_once THEME_LAYOUT_PATH . 'container.phtml';
    
    $layoutPath = 'themes/neutron/layout/' . $page . '/' . $page . '.phtml';
    
    switch($page) 
    {
        case 'home':
            include $layoutPath;
            break;
        case 'login':
            include $layoutPath;
            break;
        case 'register':
            include $layoutPath;
            break;
        default:
            include 'themes/neutron/layout/404/404.phtml';
    
    }
    
    ?>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. However, while this answer is correct, it would be improved by showing the correction to the code.